# Reformatting cumulative data

Tags: r, statistics, cumulative-frequency

I have data with the cumulative households against the cumulative wealth they posses. I've attached an image of a small amount of the data. Using the R `diff()` function allows me to get what % of households hold what % of wealth which is good.
I aim to find the Gini index of my data which I first need to get in a format where the households are evenly spaced. There are 20000 rows or so meaning I need to standardise the wealth owned to 0.005% at a time or something like that so as to attain a true distribution of wealth with households (1,2, etc) and not the percentage of households.

[image]

EDIT:

```
structure(list(ï..0.002 = c(0.005, 0.007, 0.017, 0.025, 0.027, 
0.037, 0.047, 0.057, 0.067, 0.075, 0.081, 0.09, 0.1, 0.107, 0.116, 
0.124, 0.13, 0.138, 0.145, 0.151), X.0.002 = c(-0.004, -0.005, 
-0.008, -0.01, -0.01, -0.013, -0.015, -0.017, -0.019, -0.02, 
-0.021, -0.022, -0.024, -0.025, -0.026, -0.027, -0.027, -0.028, 
-0.029, -0.03)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

Data OCR'd with https://ocr.space/ :

```
Obs wealth  households  
1   -0.002  0.002   
2   -0.004  0.005   
3   -0.005  0.007   
4   -0.008  0.017   
5   -0.01   0.025   
6   -0.01   0.027   
7   -0.013  0.037   
8   -0.015  0.047   
9   -0.017  0.057   
10  -0.019  0.067   
11  -0.02   0.075   
12  -0.021  0.081   
13  -0.022  0.09    
14  -0.024  0.1
```

Comment: Is your goal basically to estimate the probability distribution function from your data (which I assume shows an empirical cumulative distribution)?

Comment: Images are a really bad way of posting data (or code). [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the code you've tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: @RuiBarradas Hi I've just tried that, hope that helps.

Comment: @countorlok Yes essentially. Basically if I find the gini index of some empirical data then it assumes the order corresponds to say household 1,2,3 etc whereas the format I have now is in the percentage of households. Maybe I could introduce some number of households (say 60m) and the total wealth to make it easier but this may give me the wrong Gini index.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you used an interpolation to get your data into an evenly spaced form using the `approx` function.

```r
interpolation <- approx(x = df$cum_hh, y = df$cum_wealth, xout = seq(0, 1, by = 0.00005))

interpolation$x ## evenly spaced cumulative households
interpolation$y ## interpolated cumulative wealth
```